# django download multiple file which are bytestream

Tags: django, download

I have some file which saved in database with byte,how can I download these files by django.

I know the zipfile package can zip some files, but the files are exist,I want to know how zip some file's  bytestream to a zip

Answer (score 0):

To download multiple file, you will definitely want to create a zipfile and return that. Because each file is stored as a bytestream, you will want to use [ZipFile.writestr(zinfo_or_arcname, bytes[, compress_type])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr).

As an example, you would do something like this:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(fp, 'w'):
    for file_data in files:
        zipFile.writestr('name_of_file', file_data)
```

Comment: Glad you got it working :). If this works though, you can probably go ahead and mark it as resolved